# Upgrade to CiviCRM 4.3 failing on DROP FOREIGN KEY

Tags: upgrade, database

I have successfully upgraded many other CiviCRM installations over the years, but I've been unable to work my  way through this issue so far.

- Ubuntu 14.04
- MySQL 5.7.23
- Apache/2.4.7
- PHP Version 5.6.37
- Drupal 7.59
- CiviCRM 4.2.20

I am trying to upgrade CiviCRM 4.2.20 to 4.3.11. Ultimately the goal is to get to 4.6 LTS. I have tried repairing the CiviCRM schema (*this database has only 2 custom fields*), and I've also tried the `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` work around on importing the db, but I've still been unsuccessful at upgrading. I always hit this error at the stage of:

> [Error: Upgrade DB to 4.3.alpha1]
>
> ALTER TABLE civicrm_membership_type DROP FOREIGN KEY
>   FK_civicrm_membership_autorenewal_msg_id [nativecode=1091 ** Can't
>   DROP 'FK_civicrm_membership_autorenewal_msg_id'; check that column/key
>   exists]

I found a helpful thread somewhere that suggesting that MySQL 5.5 may have been the culprit, so I upgraded to MySQL 5.7, and still get the exact same error regardless of MySQL version. I have a fresh export and backups, so every time I try something it is with a fresh working version of the database on 4.2.20. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
--Tony

[image: Error: Upgrade DB to 4.3.alpha1]

**Update**
[Based on Jon G's suggestion](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26561/upgrade-to-civicrm-4-3-failing-on-drop-foreign-key?answertab=votes#tab-top) I tried commenting out [the offending lines](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourThree.php#L883-L886) in `CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourThree.php`, reloaded a fresh database for upgrading, but still continued to receive the exact same error.  The only difference this time being, after I hit refresh to try and force the upgrade to continue, then another message occurred:

> ALTER TABLE civicrm_premiums ADD COLUMN
>   premiums_nothankyou_position int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1'
>   [nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name
>   'premiums_nothankyou_position']

I couldn't grep any more lines to comment out of the `FourThree.php` upgrade file, and wasn't sure how this would affect database integrity. The suggested threads ([CRM-12458](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-12458), [CRM-11260](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11260))  seem to relate, but I was ultimately unable to use the information to solve this issue, admittedly due to the lack in my technical understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be identical to [CRM-12458](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-12458).  Which is unusual - most cases where you'd get this error were solved in [CRM-11260](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11260) but there are still edge cases that can cause this.

I would read those links in full - but my guess is you should edit `CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourThree.php`.  Remove the [four highlighted lined at this link](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourThree.php#L883-L886) - that is, lines 883-886.

Since you're dropping a foreign key constraint that doesn't exist, there should be no difference as a result of removing these lines.  Note that you may have to remove some of the following lines if you get similar errors.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I did try commenting out those lines, and the upgrade failed with the exact same message. The only difference this time being, after I hit refresh to try and force the upgrade to continue, then another message occurred:

Comment: The "Duplicate column name" suggests that perhaps you didn't restore the pre-upgrade database before trying again.  For that matter, that would also cause the original issue you're describing.

Comment: Thank you again for your guidance. I also attempted the upgrade with the previous version of the database restored from last weeks's pre-upgraded CiviCRM 4.2.8 (_to an new freshly created empty MySQL database_), and still receive the same error.  The 4.2.8 version is the oldest backup I have, so it seems something has already gone awry with the `FK_civicrm_membership_autorenewal_msg_id` in whatever backup database copies I have as well.  We'll stay with v4.2.20 for the time being. Thanks again!

Comment: 4.2 is VERY old and has known security issues.  While you might have to deal with a handful of fields like this, my guess is that you don't have anything of value in the `civicrm_premiums.premiums_nothankyou_position` field.  If not, simply drop the column from your database schema and retry this.