# Civicrm Migration Giving Foreign Key consrtant error

Tags: drupal

I am migrating civicrm from version 4.2.9 to 5.16.0. While running the upgrade url 
giving this error "ALTER TABLE civicrm_membership_type DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_civicrm_membership_autorenewal_msg_id [nativecode=1091 ** Can't DROP 'FK_civicrm_membership_autorenewal_msg_id'; check that column/key exists]". But I didn't find that consrtaints for that table.
Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: I think this is the same as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/26563/181. Try commenting out the 4 lines that it says in the 2nd paragraph there.

Comment: Yup thanks. I solved that problem while commenting four lines. but now I am getting another problem that "SELECT id, name FROM civicrm_contribution_type WHERE name IN ('Donation', 'Event Fee', 'Member Dues') AND is_active =1 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'vvki_in_civicrm_1_4.2.9.civicrm_contribution_type' doesn't exist]". That "civicrm_contribution_type" table not exists in 4.2.9 database. Please help me for this too.

Comment: It sounds like you might have several issues that need ongoing help for upgrading such an old database. Consider contacting someone on the partners list: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors