# Civicrm Upgrade to 4.7.23

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am planning to upgrade civicrm from version 4.2.9 to 4.7.23. For this can I directly upgrade it from 4.2.9 to 4.7.23? Or any other version I have to upgrade first and then to move to 4.7.23. Please suggest me steps for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But make sure you are on 4.2.9, because

> "If you are starting from a version prior to 4.2.9 you should upgrade to the latest 4.2 version as an interim step, as the latest version does not contain upgrade code going back that far."

and

> "You can make big jumps in one upgrade (e.g. 4.5.2 to 4.7.20) without
>   needing to apply all the upgrades in between."

The above quotes are from, and see more at:  https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/ .

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: and Prasad if that answer ^^^ works for you, please choose it as 'correct'/preferred, whatever :) . Thanks.  I'm trying to 'level up'.

Comment: I am getting error as "Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA." while upgrading this

Comment: Aha Prasad, hmm. Also post the error message in town square channel at chat.civicrm.org .

Comment: @prasad kanalli can you confirm the steps you're taking leading up to seeing the [installation canary](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/8b9a8f4abb25cfa7a498eaaa3e459e4d313e350a/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php) error? I don't expect it to show up during *upgrade*. Unfortunately you'll need to do this by posting comments until you get a few more reputation points on this website 

Comment: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33312/civicrm-upgrade-from-4-2-9-to-4-7-23 - Jon has given more detail over there. Looks like you may need to solve  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/civicrm-migration-giving-foreign-key-consrtant-error as well first?

Comment: @prasadkanalli it is likely that some upgrader steps may fail.  If that happens you should manually apply to the next release and then continue with the upgrade.  Make sure you have backups!