# Civicrm upgrade from 4.2.9 to 4.7.23

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I am upgrading 4.2.9 to 4.7.23. But while database upgrade i got error as "Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA". As I researched, I deleted the table "civicrm_install_canary" but again the table creating dynamically. I didn't get any solution.  Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you upgrading civicrm directly to 4.7.23 ? if yes, 4.2.9 is quite old version, should upgrade it into multiple steps, and take backup at completion of each step.
4.2.9 -> 4.2.recent,
4.2.recent -> 4.4.recent,
4.4.recent -> 4.6.recent,
4.6.recent -> 4.7.23.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an installation canary error, that means you tried upgrading once and it failed - and then when you upgraded a second time, you got the installation canary error.  The original error is the "true" error.  You can probably ffind it in your [ConfigAndLog logs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories).  However, you should restore your pre-upgrade backup before attempting another upgrade.  Fixing a broken upgrade is a very advanced topic.